# What does the phrase "To be much for" mean?

Tags: meaning, british-english, sentence, phrase-meaning

'There dosen't seem to be much for correlation between intelligence, and kindness.' (['Genocide Bingo'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4kDPxbS6ofw) by Exurb1a on YouTube)

What does 'there dosen't seem to be much for' mean?

It's the 'for' that's confusing me.

Comment: It is always helpful for you to reference you source. Is this it?  **Quick study: Satoshi Kanazawa on intelligence The disadvantage of smarts**

Comment: I've added it in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a mis-hearing of the words.;

Comment: The ***closed captions*** say "much of a correlation between ...." And listening, I think this is indeed what they said (although the first part of the *of* is kind of slurred, so it sounds somewhat like *for*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does 'there doesn't seem to be much for' mean?  [Genocide Bingo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4kDPxbS6ofw)

It's the lack of correlation between higher IQ's and kindness. He uses dolphins as present examples. And the author extrapolates to the future if and when AI's are in a position of control.